# PDFObject.js embed pdf byte array

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfobject

I am using PDFObject.js to load PDF document in JSF pages.

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{observerMBean.fileName}" id="hidden"/>

 <script>
 var hid="./Documents/"+$("#hidden").val();              
 var options = {
    pdfOpenParams: {
    navpanes: 0,
    toolbar: 0,
    statusbar: 0,                           
    view: "fitH",               
    },
    forcePDFJS: true,                   
    };
   var myPDF = PDFObject.embed(hid, "#pdf", options);
</script>
```

This is working when the embed parameter is PDF url , but I need to use byte [] as well . How to pass byte [] to PDFObject embed function?